# Creating and populating dynamically named arrays in bash

Tags: bash

I am creating dynamic arrays which all have different letters in their name. For the purpose of this question, my initial array of letters has been set at a fixed length. However, in my final implementation this letter array will be any length.

1. For each letter, I construct a string
2. I declare a new array with that string, making use of `eval` to evaluate the variable's value within the `declare` command.
3. I add some values to the array, again using `eval` to evaluate any variable values.

Here is the code:

```
declare -a LETTER_ARRAY=( "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" ) 
for i in "${LETTER_ARRAY[@]}"
do
    name_string="apple${i}"
    color0="red"
    color1="green"
    eval "declare -a ${name_string}_array"
    eval "${name_string}_array[0]=$color0"
    eval "${name_string}_array[1]=$color1"
done
```

So, how can I iterate through these dynamic arrays and echo what is in them? I have tried the following:

```
for i in "${LETTER_ARRAY[@]}"
do
    eval "array_name='apple${i}_array'"
    echo ${array_name[0]}
done
```

This has not worked for me. I can confirm that my dynamic arrays were successfully created and populated, as when I echo out a value manually, I get a result:

```
echo ${appleA_array[0]}
red
```

Comment: You declared the first array under the name `appleA_array` but then claimed that `echo ${AZa_ARRAY[0]}` would print `red`. Could it be that you ran different code from the one shown here?

Comment: Apologies. Changed the names for this question. Fixed this in the description now

Comment: `declare -a LETTER_ARRAY = [ "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" ] ` is invalid. Bash is space aware. Why are you writing such code? What is the problem you are trying to solve? What is the point of creating such arrays, when it's so hard to use them, as you noticed? And also missing a `do` after `for`.

Comment: Furthermore, arrays are defined using `()`. `[]` does not work here.

Comment: @x3nr0s Thanks for the fix. However, there is still a name difference. `appleA_array` != `appleA_ARRAY`. Also, the first `for` is missing a `do`.

Comment: Sorry guys. Terrible syntax errors from me. Fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A perfect place to use a namereference:

```
letter_array=(A B C D E) 
for i in "${letter_array[@]}"; do
     declare -n var="apple${i}_array"
     var[0]=red
     var[1]=green
done
declare -p appleA_array
```

would output:

```
declare -a appleA_array=([0]="red" [1]="green")
```

> how can I iterate through these dynamic arrays and echo what is in them?

With the above:

```
for i in "${letter_array[@]}"; do
    declare -n var="apple${i}_array"
    printf "%s\n" "${var[0]}"
done
```

Notes:

- Do not use eval. [Eval is evil](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).
- Do not use upper case variables, by convention they are used for exported variables, like COLUMNS, PWD, UID, EUID, LINES. Use lower case variables in your scripts.
- Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net for most common mistakes

---

But if you are creating a 2d array, then an associative array might be better:

```
declare -A apple_arrays
letter_array=(A B C D E) 
for i in "${letter_array[@]}"; do
     apple_arrays[$i,0]=red
     apple_arrays[$i,1]=green
done
for i in "${letter_array[@]}"; do
     printf "one=%s two=%s\n" "${apple_arrays[$i,0]}" "${apple_arrays[$i,1]}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks. Is nameref suitable in regards to compatibility with older versions of bash? For example I believe MacOS uses older bash without namereference

Comment: I think nameref was introduced in bash4.3 . Then you should have added all the relevant info in the question. And folks on macos seem to switch to zsh from bash.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I iterate through these dynamic arrays

`echo ${array_name[0]}` does not work because `array_name` is not the name of an array; `$array_name` is. Therefore, `eval "echo \"\${${array_name}[0]}\""` would to the trick.

However, I'd recommend namerefs.
By The way: `declare` works without `eval` and is more reliable that way.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

letters=({A..E})
for i in "${letters[@]}"; do
    declare -a "apple${i}_array=(red green)"
done

for i in "${letters[@]}"; do
    declare -n array="apple${i}_array"
    # now you can use `array` as if it was `appleA_array`, `appleB_array`, ...
    echo "${array[0]}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first line is not bash syntax. If I try the line

```
declare -a LETTER_ARRAY = [ "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" ]
```

I get:

```
bash: declare: `=': not a valid identifier
bash: declare: `[': not a valid identifier
bash: declare: `]': not a valid identifier
```

I think, you get similar error messages, but you ignored them

More errors:

- Forgotten `do`
- case mismatch: suffix on definition: `_array`, and for output: `_ARRAY`
- Use always double quotes when using `[@]`

One correct syntax is:

```
declare -a LETTER_ARRAY=( "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" )

for i in "${LETTER_ARRAY[@]}"
do
    name_string="apple${i}"
    color0="red"
    color1="green"
    eval "declare -a ${name_string}_array"
    echo "${name_string}_array[0]=$color0"
    eval "${name_string}_array[0]=$color0"
    eval "${name_string}_array[1]=$color1"
done

echo ${appleA_array[0]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- yes, I'm aware of these bash syntax errors, this was due to my error in creating an example for this. My version I'm using on my PC doesn't have these errors. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `eval "array_name='AZ${i}_ARRAY'"` makes `array_name` a scalar, not an array. Arrays in bash are usually created like this

```
arr=( your elements go here )
```

If you want to assign one array to another, you have to interpolate the elements between those parenthesis, for instance:

```
arr=(  ${other_array[@]} )
```

Since you are using bash, this would perform word splitting the elements of `other_array`, if they contain spaces. Hence you would usually write it for the safe side as

```
arr=( "${other_array[@]}" )
```

Hence, for your case, you could do a

```
eval "array_name=( \${AZ${i}_ARRAY[@]} )"
```

This causes an array `array_name` to be created, with the elements of the respective AZi_ARRAY.

I omitted here for simplicity the prevention against word splitting, because in your example, the array elements contain single words only.